# How to give a parameter in Jenkinsfile without using pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, cicd

I just want to add a boolean parameter where a user can tick it and it just prints some text to the build description.

When I used pipeline, agent any, parameters; It's acutally expecting for a stage but I don't want this to be linked to any stage of the pipeline.

```
// It should go like this
booleanParam(name: 'A', 
             description: 'Print This.'
             defaultValue: false
)

if (params.A == true) {
    jenkinsUtils.appendBuildDescrition("Box is Ticked!!")
}
```

This was the approach I've tried but it failed as I'm unable to see the checkbox option while building the Jenkins job. Any tips on how to proceed.

Thanks in Advance, Cheers!!

Comment: Just trying to test this one in the feature branch before merging into the main branch.

Answer (score 0):

according to your comment, I suspect that you are not running the code you want to run. I suggest tp verify that this code indeed runs - by adding a print to the console, and by the way, printing the value of params.A will give you a good clue to what that happens if the correct code **does** indeed run.